# Help me!!!! Profit is going down

Tags: software-center

I have a game on Ubuntu Software Center. It costs 5 $. But I only get 4$. Ok. But, when my 2nd buyer bought, instead of having 8$, I had 7.20$. Now, I got a third buyer and I have 10.40$ instaed of 12$. Why????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is already here, [CLICK HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70645/how-is-tax-handled-for-purchases-from-the-ubuntu-software-centre) to read it (scroll down a bit).
Don't desist, the world needs more games. ;-)